# Using bacnet stm32f10x routines, how to add MSTP_Slave_Node_FSM (I want to use automac

Tags: slave, bacnet

I checked dlmstp.c in /port/stm32f10x and found that only master has no slave, because I need automac but there is no MSTP_Slave_Node_FSM in the process, what should I do.

I use device A (master) to send WhoIs to device B (slave), but device B fails to send I_AM

Comment: I think the question could do with some more clarification; but have you tried with a (client) app like 'YABE' or 'VTS' (?).  Sounds like a connectivity issue or even configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

When sending a Who-IS message to a MSTP Slave device you need to address it specifically as a directed message instead of a broadcast message (0xFF).